# Folder structure for a PHP project

Tags: php, design-patterns

I've decided to completely rewrite my old PHP project from the ground up. Before, I had one file for each page and now I'd like to use MVC pattern approach with one point of entry instead. The project itself is quite big and I'm trying to build my own framework so I can integrate everything nicely.

I've searched stackoverflow for similar questions and I've found some but they had quite different folder structures so I decided to post my own.

### Folder structure so far

```
/applications
    /administration
        /private
            /controllers
            /models
            /views
            configuration.php
        /public
            /ajax
            /fonts
            /icons
            /images
            /stylesheets
        index.php
    /website
        /private
            /controllers
            /models
            /views
            configuration.php
        /public
            /ajax
            /fonts
            /icons
            /images
            /stylesheets
        index.php
/backups
/library
    /helpers
        datetime.php
        text.php
    controller.php
    model.php
```

### Details

- **/applications** - I've separated administration from the normal website and I'll also use different sub-domain for the administration.
- **/applications/app/private** - Access to this folder is blocked by nginx.
- **/applications/app/public** - As the name suggests, everything that's visible on the web.
- **/applications/app/index.php** - Entry point for each website.
- **/backups** - Database backups.
- **/library** - Base controllers / models reside here.
- **/library/helpers** - All helper classes that will be used in both websites are here so I don't need to copy/paste them into both applications.

### Main questions

Is this a good way to structure my website or would you do things differently? Are there any pitfalls I might encounter with this structure? Is there anything I'm missing?

All help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using a similar structure (with homemade framework too but backup out of webroot). You could maybe add a "form" folder in the private folder.

I use this to make controller more readable. The forms are generaly a big wall of object code. Putting them in an external file included in the controller is a good idea.

Don't forget to exclude the public folder from the rewriting rules and everything should be allright :)

An other solution is to put index.php in your public folder and define this folder as your webroot in nginx. It prevent remote access to all other file (like backup file) which should used only by the framework.

```
/applications
    /administration
        /private
            /controllers
            /models
            /views
            configuration.php
        /public <---- Vhost WebRoot
            /ajax
            /fonts
            /icons
            /images
            /stylesheets
            index.php
    /website
        /private
            /controllers
            /models
            /views
            configuration.php
        /public <---- Vhost WebRoot
            /ajax
            /fonts
            /icons
            /images
            /stylesheets
            index.php
/backups
/library
    /helpers
        datetime.php
        text.php
    controller.php
    model.php
```

Answer (score 8):

The MVC pattern has **absolutely nothing** to do with your application's folder layout.

Whether you put all your files into one single folder or use a layout like shown in your question is completely irrelevant. It's not getting more or less MVC from it, because MVC is not about folders, but about [*splitting user interface interaction into three distinct roles*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html).

Unless you are following a code convention that demands a certain file naming scheme (like PEAR), the only thing important for your application is that your Autoloader can find the files at runtime *somehow*. So if you think the layout shown above is good for you, go with it.

[Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin suggests that your folder layout should express what the application is about.](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2011/09/30/Screaming-Architecture.html):

> Your architectures should tell readers about the system, not about the frameworks you used in your system. If you are building a health-care system, then when new programmers look at the source repository, their first impression should be: “Oh, this is a heath-care system”. Those new programmers should be able to learn all the use cases of the system, and still not know how the system is delivered. They may come to you and say: “We see some things that look sorta like models, but where are the views and controllers”, and you should say: “Oh, those are details that needn’t concern you at the moment, we’ll show them to you later.”

Comment: I think that pretty much sums it up. The fixed directory and include naming scheme is used in lieu of an autoloader, not because the application design demands it.

Answer (score 2):

Quick note: I would stay away from public/private folders as you're essentially locking yourself into two roles. An ACL implementation would be difficult/confusing in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess administration and website is different modules of website.

Why dont you have a shared or core modules folder. For example, you have a database model named "User" and methods named createUser(), editUser(), listUsers(), changeRightsOfUser() and more more.. With this structure you need to write and abstract this model for all modules.

Your controllers is must be unique, this is okey. But models can be usable or extendable for every module.